# Preventing ajax call with some form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a working javascript funciton with an ajax call, and the post call works perfectly upon button submission.

I just am trying to add in some validation but even when input is invalid it still submits ajax and refreshes the page.

All I'm trying to do here is make sure the number fields are only numeric and that all required fields are not empty, but if I test it with empty input, or put 'ONE' in one of the fields that expects numbers (as opposed to '1') it still calls ajax, which inserts the record, and then refreshes the page. SHould I be doing my if statements using the ID of each input field instead of my already set variables for the input 'name'?

```
$("#save").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    var IDNumber = $("input[name=IDNumber]").val();
    var IDName2 = $("input[name=IDName2]").val();
    var IDNumber2 = $("input[name=IDNumber2]").val();
    var Number3 = $("input[name=Number3]").val();
    var ExtraName = $("input[name=ExtraName]").val();
    var category = $("input[name=category]").val();

    if(isNaN(IDNumber) || isNaN(IDNumber2) || isNaN(Number3)){
        alert('Fields must be numeric');
    }else if(name == '' || 
            IDNumber == '' || 
            IDName2 == '' || 
            IDNumber2 == '' || 
            Number3 == '' || 
            ExtraName == '' || 
            category == '')
    {
        alert('You must fill out all required fields';)
    }else{

        //perform the working ajax
    }
}
```

Comment: Will using the required, and type=number attributes on the input field work in the browser you are coding for? [See this for reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) Also, instead of .click, add a .submit to the form element instead.

Comment: just to clarify, the alerts shows but the ajaxs perform, or no alerts shows ?

Comment: Can you log all values to console, and see what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: The alerts do not currently show

Comment: Yeah there's something wrong with your if condition, log all values to console and see what's wrong

Comment: Yeah they log with the input that I'm typing in there

Comment: What does your html look like

Comment: Try this: give your input an id (EX: <input type="text" id="IDNumber"  />) then use var IDNumber = $('#IDNumber').val();

Comment: Open the browser JS debugger and put a breakpoint on the first "if" line `if(isNaN(IDNumber) ...`. Is that breakpoint hit? Inspect the values of all the vars you'd set `var name =...` in the debugger; are they what you expect (empty)? In the debugger console type simply `$("input[name=IDNumber]")` - the console output should be a jQuery element object which you can inspect. Are the `$` selectors getting the actual elements you expect? As @acaputo said, show us (some of) the actual HTML this is executing on.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon is inside the alert method for the missing required fields. Try it again and see if it works! And it is much better if it is a submit event instead of just a click. And assuming your selector is for the button, selector should be on the form not on the button.

```
$("#save").submit(function(e){ /* Should be a submit event */

    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    var IDNumber = $("input[name=IDNumber]").val();
    var IDName2 = $("input[name=IDName2]").val();
    var IDNumber2 = $("input[name=IDNumber2]").val();
    var Number3 = $("input[name=Number3]").val();
    var ExtraName = $("input[name=ExtraName]").val();
    var category = $("input[name=category]").val();

   if(isNaN(IDNumber) || isNaN(IDNumber2) || isNaN(Number3)) {
        alert('Fields must be numeric');
    } else if(name == ''|| IDNumber == '' || IDName2 == '' || IDNumber2 == '' || Number3 == '' || ExtraName == '' || category == '') {
        alert('You must fill out all required fields'); /* Put semicolon outside */
   } else {
        /* AJAX CODE HERE */
   }
}); /* another syntax error right here */
```